# Auto setup a docker Image with ci runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am doing a server that has `gitlab` and `gitci`, both are working fine at the moment, but there are no runners.

I'm trying to use [this runner](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/lemonbar/gitlab-runner-jdk-maven/), and managed to do it locally, but now I'm trying to create a service to launch the setup with my credentials (they are correct) and it doesn't work or throw any error.

Here's my .service:

```
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill gitlab-runner-jdk-maven

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm gitlab-runner-jdk-maven

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull lemonbar/gitlab-runner-jdk-maven:1.0

ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name gitlab-runner-jdk-maven -P -d \
-e 'CI_SERVER_URL=myserver -e 'REGISTRATION_TOKEN=mytoken'\
-v /opt/gitlab-runner-jdk-maven:/home/gitlab_ci_runner/data \
    lemonbar/gitlab-runner-jdk-maven:1.0 app:setup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it myself after a lot of trial error, you only need to app setup once and the runner will be mounted automatically whenever its needed.

Note:if you make a runner a service don't freak out if its not working (because it will only show its working when its compiling something)